# Unable to delete trace in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, xml-namespaces, xmla

I created a trace in SSAS but I'm unable to delete it.
Fairly new to SSAS and not really sure how to get around this.
Version: 14.0.249.83

Tried deleting it with this:

```
<Delete xmlns="https://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine" xmlns:soap="https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<Object>
<TraceID>12345</TraceID>
</Object>
</Delete>
```

But I end up with this error.

```
Executing the query ...
The Delete element at line 7, column 146 (namespace https://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine) cannot appear under Envelope/Body/Execute/Command.
Run complete
```

Comment: The namespace is actually `http://schemas.microsoft.com...`, not `https`.

Comment: Seems right! will try it thanks